# How to find the relationship between angle an and angle b from the equality relation?

Tags: trigonometry

```
TrigFactor[Cos[a]/(1 + Sin[a]) == Sin[2 b]/(1 + cos[2 b]), 
  c == (2 \[Pi])/3, a + b + c == \[Pi], 0 < a < \[Pi], 
  0 < b < \[Pi], 
  0 < c < \[Pi]]
```

In a triangle, the functional relationship between angle an and angle b satisfies the above relationship. How can we find the angle relationship between angle an and angle b?

Comment: How is `an` definded? In your relationship I only see `a,b,c` (probably the angles of the triangle)

Answer (score 0):

From: `c==2/3 Pi` we conclude `a+b== 1/3 Pi`. Therefore:

```
Solve[{Cos[a]/(1 + Sin[a]) == Sin[2 b]/(1 + cos[2 b])}, {a}]
```

[image]

Comment: The desired result is the relationship between angles. To get a+2b==pi/2

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR The angles $a$ and $b$ are equal.

Computers in general and Mathematica specifically are picky. Typographical errors and mismatched bracketing upset them and cause wrong answers.

After correcting what I preceived as typographical errors and adding a few "wrappers" that found relevant, answer became $0$.

```mma
FullSimplify[TrigToExp[a - b /. 
    ToRules[Reduce[{TrigFactor[Cos[a]/(1 + Sin[a]) == 
         Sin[2*b]/(1 + Cos[2*b])], c == (2*Pi)/3, 
       a + b + c == Pi, 0 < a < Pi, 0 < b < Pi, 0 < c < Pi}]]]]
```